# .htaccess RewriteBase equivalent for WordPress - Passing a URL as a variable without getting a 404

Tags: url-rewriting, gallery, rewrite-rules

I have a page ran by a javascript plugin that changes the url every time a slide in a gallery is cycled.

This means that while slide 1 is visible, the URL is `http://www.sitename.com/gallery/slide1/` and while slide 2 is visible, the URL is `http://www.sitename.com/gallery/slide2/` ... and so on.

Outside of WordPress, I used the RewriteBase command in an .htaccess file to make it so that when a user goes to `http://www.sitename.com/gallery/slide2/` they're directed to a page where slide 2 is visible.

However, I cannot find a way to make this happen in WordPress. Is there a way to pass this information as a variable without using a format like `http://www.sitename.com/gallery?slide=slide2`

The script I'm currently using is:

```
// change url - unless IE8 because IE8 hates life
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9) {} else {
    $histimg = img.name.toLowerCase();
    var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
    history.replaceState(stateObj, "", pathname + imageprefix + $histimg + "/");
}
```

Then, when a link is accepted, I run this to find out which plan to display:

```
patharr = location.pathname.split("/").reverse(); //Get the URL of the page

result = patharr[1]; // Get the Slide Number

$('#xmenu button[data-index="' + result + '"]').trigger("click");

}
```

NOTE: I do not wish to accomplish this with a plugin, or by hacking files directly inside of the WordPress installation. This is part of a theme and needs to be contained within the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't give you exactly that format, but you could add a rewrite endpoint named `slide` and get the format `http://www.sitename.com/gallery/slide/2/`:

```
function wpd_add_slide_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'slide', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_slide_endpoint' );
```

Then you could [localize your script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass the slide number, using `get_query_var('slide')` to fetch the current value.

Comment: I don't think I need to localize my script. My script should be able to handle that just by dissecting the URL, right? However, I am wondering how this `add_rewrite_endpoint` function works. Right now, I am just getting a 404 page when I try to visit `http://www.sitename.com/gallery/slide/2/`... how would I configure this snippet of code to get things working?

Comment: Yes, you could just extract it from the URL with javascript without having to pass it to your script via php. When you add or modify rewrite rules, the rules need to be flushed before new ones are recognized, because regenerating rules is an expensive operation. The easiest way to flush the rules is to just visit the Settings > Permalinks page.